# jquery how to uncheck a radio button in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio button.

and this is my jquery code to unselect the radio button when the other one becomes selected.

```
 $("#RdbToday").click(function () {
        $("#RdbDateRange").attr("checked", false);
    }); 
    $("#RdbDateRange").click(function () {
        $("#RdbToday").attr("checked", false);
    });
```

It is not working. which means that when I select the first one, the other one still on. also I can't unchecked the radio button once I checked it. why?

Comment: Why to use jquery instead you can have html group name property?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Millind's answer right i am posting this alternative way you can use prop `name`

of html 
Like this

```
<input type="radio" name="foo">
<input type="radio" name="foo" checked>
<input type="radio" name="foo">
```

See working demo

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/UqHGK/)

As your comment says you are using asp.net then its very simple to use **groupname** attribute Read here.....[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: last thing please. the .click is not working on the radio button. why please? i need to do some actions when a specific radio button is selected. how please? .click is not working

Comment: it didn't work. check my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106834/jquery-make-even-when-radio-button-becomes-selected

Answer (score 2):

use `.prop()` instead:

```
$('radio_btn_selector').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: I am working on IE8. does that `prop()` works on that "intelligent" browser please?

Comment: I tried your solution, it is not working. still nothing changing

Comment: @user3432257:can you create the fiddle??