# Change div visibility when radio button becomes selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a div and I want to show it when the user selects a specific radio button. Also, I need to hide the div when the user selects another radio button.

I tried this;

```
$("#RdbToday").click(function () {
        $("#dateSelectorSpan").hide();
    }); 
    $("#RdbDateRange").click(function () {
        $("#dateSelectorSpan").show();
    });
```

For some reasons the `.click` is not working. I tried to make `alert` inside each function but the alert didn't fired.

I also tried to user `.change` but the same results.

#### Edit

I already included the jquery library and I have alot of jquery functions working.

here the all code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //LoadCallsPerCampign();
    //showTotalCallsStatuses();
    //showInboundCalls();
    //LoadServiceLevel();

    $("#RdbToday").change(function () {
        $("#dateSelectorSpan").hide();
    }); 
    $("#RdbDateRange").change(function () {
        $("#dateSelectorSpan").show();
    });
})
```

#### edit 2

this is the html

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RdbToday" Text="Today" Font-Names="Calibri" GroupName="foo"/>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RdbDateRange" Text="Date Range:" Font-Names="Calibri" GroupName="foo"/>
                <span id="dateSelectorSpan">
                    <input type="text" id="CldrFrom" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" placeholder="From" style="width:15%" />
                    <input type="text" id="CldrTo" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" placeholder="To" style="width:15%"/>
                </span>
```

#### edit 3

for who needs the actual html. this is it

```
<span style="font-family:Calibri;"><input id="RdbToday" type="radio" name="foo" value="RdbToday"><label for="RdbToday">Today</label></span>
<span style="font-family:Calibri;"><input id="RdbDateRange" type="radio" name="foo" value="RdbDateRange"><label for="RdbDateRange">Date Range:</label></span>
<span id="dateSelectorSpan">
                    <input name="CldrFrom" type="text" id="CldrFrom" placeholder="From" style="width:15%">
                    <input name="CldrTo" type="text" id="CldrTo" placeholder="To" style="width:15%">
                </span>
```

Comment: The the handlers in document.ready and make sure you have jQuery added

Comment: @Adil yes that code in the document .ready also, I have a lot of jquery functions. I already included the library

Comment: Please Show us the html you have

Comment: Are these radio buttons added dynamically, if ya, delegate event. Or maybe, wrong selectors are used

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/LcT3h/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff no they are in the dom.

Comment: @Adil I edited the question and added the html

Comment: What's the rendered ID's of the radio buttons?

Comment: Have you checked the output HTML that the id's really are `RdbToday` and `RdbDateRange`? ASP.NET will change those id's if they're within a container!

Comment: @DaveParsons the same as in question. i checked that now

Comment: @Jamiec yes man. I am aware to these things. I have checked that on the browser

Comment: Of course your IDs are unique on document context, right?!

Comment: @A.Wolff yes sure. i also edited the question third time

Comment: Your question is unanswerable unless you can provide us a small, self-contained example which demonstrates the problem. Use something like http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: So i really don't see what could be your issue except maybe a cache problem. Now you should test it on different browsers and provide a jsfiddle or online link where your issue can be checked

Comment: You say you have a lot of jquery functions - are any of those other functions also acting on these radio buttons? Any console errors?

Comment: @Jamiec I can't give you a jsfiddle. it is asp.net code

Comment: @DaveParsons no i don't have functions on radio button. all my functions on buttons. also, I will check if there is any error on consoles

Comment: asp.net just outputs HTML, jQuery only operates on HTML. asp.net is inconsequential - you already ruled that out as the problem.

Comment: hey guys. I found the problem. I was executing a web service before my code. that web service has a problem. when I hide the code of it. it works fine. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `ClientID` in javascript not the server id as asp.net will generate the new CliendID for server controls and the selector you have wont find element by that id.

```
$("#<%= RdbToday.ClientID %>").change(function () {
    $("#dateSelectorSpan").hide();
}); 
$("#<%= RdbDateRange.ClientID %>").change(function () {
    $("#dateSelectorSpan").show();
});
```

**Edit**

The code you have is working.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pd259/)

```
$("#RdbToday").change(function () {
    $("#dateSelectorSpan").hide();
});
$("#RdbDateRange").change(function () {
    $("#dateSelectorSpan").show();
});
```

Comment: that is wrong. please check my edit 3. the id is not changed

Comment: Your code is working check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/pd259/